# how to realloc an empty 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I have a function which is called several times, with a parameter `n` which defines the `n*2`-sized 2d array:

```
void myfunc(int n){

  static int n0=0,i;
  static double **x=NULL;

  if(n>n0){ //realloc if n grows
    x=(double **)realloc(x,n*sizeof(double*)));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      x[i]=(double *)realloc(x[i],2*sizeof(double))); // <--problem here
    }
    n0=n;
  }

}
```

At the first call the `**x` is initialized to `NULL`, but `x[i]` are not, and thus the second `realloc` may behave not correctly.

Is there a way to `realloc` the rows of an empty 2d matrix, without first using `malloc` or `calloc`?

Comment: A pointer to pointer is not a 2D array.

Comment: In C++? Not like that! Please pick *one* language, C and C++ are two *very* different languages, and no sane C++ programmer would do something like that.

Comment: ok, I've removed c++ flag.

Comment: As for your problem, you *do* know if the function is called the first time not. Think about what you initialize `x` to...

Comment: @EugeneSh.  what's the difference? I have rows and columns...

Comment: The difference is that a 2D array is a *contiguous* memory region with fixed dimensions. In your case it is pointing to different regions, and each "row" might have a different number of "columns".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude of course I know, but I'd like to understand if in principle is possible to use `realloc` to initialize an empty matrix, so not to conditionally use `malloc` or `realloc` depending if it's the first call or not

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you for the information, let's call it a 2d matrix then

Comment: In that case, no. `realloc` only reallocates the memory, it does not initialize otherwise uninitialized parts of the memory.

Comment: @cipper You removed the C++ tag, thus the casting of the return value of realloc is not necessary if you really are using C and not C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I did not know about such difference regarding casting, thank you.

Comment: Don't malloc an array of 2 doubles. It's a waste of electrons. Try making `x` a pointer to `double[2]`, rather than a pointer to `double*`. Also, `myfunc(int n)` is not C anymore. Try getting a modern textbook.

Comment: If you have a different answer to add, please use the "Answer Button" at the bottom of the page. Your revision was rolled back as your answer doesn't belong with your question.

Comment: @n.m.:  I see your point, but I was afraid that for very large `n` there would be stack issues
@K.Dᴀᴠɪs: ok thank you

Comment: It isn't quite clear why you were afraid of that. There are no automatic arrays of size `n` anywhere.

Comment: "Is there a way to realloc the rows of an empty 2d matrix, without first using malloc or calloc?" Yes.  `x[i]] = NULL; x[i]=(double *)realloc(x[i],2*sizeof(double)));`, yet `x[i]= malloc(sizeof *(x[i]) * 2);` is tighter code.

Answer (score 4):

Here, you should be using `malloc()` instead of `realloc()` since you are not *re*-allocating memory here.

But if your code can't know if the data is new, it should first be initialized to `NULL` in order for `realloc()` to work.

Comment: If `myfunc` is called multiple times with different values for `n`, then it's okay IMO. Well, okay if it wasn't full of other problems.

Comment: I cannot use `malloc` because at successive calls would create memory leaks. I need `realloc`, and I don't know if data is new.

Comment: @dude: if you say there are problems please enumerate them

Answer (score 1):

I would change the function to use `malloc` the first time and `realloc` after that.

However, there is no need to `realloc` for the current elements of `x`. You only need to use `malloc` for the new elements of `x`.

```
void myfunc(int n)
{
   static int n0 = 0;
   static double **x = NULL;

   if ( n > n0)
   {
      if ( x == NULL )
      {
         // Use malloc to get memory for x
         x = malloc(n*sizeof(double*));

         for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         {
            x[i] = malloc(2*sizeof(double));
         }
      }
      else
      {
         // Use realloc to get more memory for x.
         x = realloc(x, n*sizeof(double*));

         // Allocate memory only for the new elements of x.
         for( int i = n0; i < n; i++)
         {
            x[i] = malloc(2*sizeof(double));
         }
      }

      n0 = n;
   }
}
```

**PS** Don't cast the return value of `malloc` or `realloc`. See [Specifically, what's dangerous about casting the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc) to understand why.

---

After a little bit of thought, I realized the function can be simplified a bit.

```
void myfunc(int n)
{
   static int n0 = 0;
   static double **x = NULL;

   if ( n > n0)
   {
      if ( x == NULL )
      {
         // Use malloc
         x = malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
      }
      else
      {
         // Use realloc
         x = realloc(x, n*sizeof(double*));
      }

      // Use malloc for the new elements of x.
      // When n0 is 0, it will be all of them.
      for( int i = n0; i < n; i++)
      {
         x[i] = malloc(2*sizeof(double));
      }

      n0 = n;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your tip about casting. About the solution, then it might be easier to just add a line before the second realloc:
`if(n0==0) x[i]=NULL;`

Comment: @cipper, what do you hope to gain from that?

Comment: @cipper, see the updated answer. You can decide whether you need to use `x[i] = NULL;` at all.

Comment: @R Sahu: yes, by restricting the loop to `n0..n` it also solves. Nice idea, thank you!

Comment: @R Sahu: but thinking again, after `realloc` do x[0]..x[n0] remain unchanged? don't they need to be also reallocated?

Comment: @cipper, yes, they will remain unchanged. That's the whole point of `realloc`. It will preserve the old values.

Comment: @cipper, from http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc: *expanding or contracting the existing area pointed to by ptr, if possible. The contents of the area remain unchanged up to the lesser of the new and old sizes. If the area is expanded, the contents of the new part of the array are undefined.*

Comment: `if ( x == NULL )
      {
         // Use malloc
         x = malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
      }
      else` not needed.  Can be deleted and achieve same functionality.

Comment: @chux, is `realloc` guaranteed to be a noop if the size does not change?

Comment: @RSahu No.  Yet that does not affect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014310/how-to-realloc-an-empty-2d-array).  `realloc(x, n*sizeof(double*));` is OK when `x == NULL`.

Comment: @chux, thanks for the clarification. I'll leave the code as is. It just seems cleaner from logic perspective.

Answer (score 1):

```
void myfunc(int n){

  static int n0=0,i;
  static double **x=NULL;

  if(n>n0){
    x=realloc(x,n*sizeof(double*)));
    for(i=n0;i<n;i++){
      x[i]=malloc(2*sizeof(double)));
    }
    n0=n;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to various answer detailing how to increase the allocation, code could be altered to allow an eventual freeing of the allocation by calling with `myfunc(0)`.

Also better to use `size_t` for array sizing.

No need for `i` to be `static`.

This function hides its result, perhaps return the pointer?

```
double **myfunc(size_t n) {
  static size_t n0 = 0;
  static double **x = NULL;

  if (n > n0) {
    void *new_ptr = realloc(x, sizeof *x * n);
    if (new_ptr == NULL) {
      TBD_Code();  // Handle out-of-memory
    }
    x = new_ptr;
    for (size_t i = n0; i < n; i++) {
      x[i] = malloc(sizeof *(x[i]) * 2);
    }
    n0 = n;
  } else if (n == 0) {
    while (n0 > 0) [
      free(x[--n0]);
    }
    free(x);
    x = NULL;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Consider `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * n);` style of using `*alloc()`.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain than `ptr = malloc(sizeof (de-referenced_ptr_type) * n);`